Laravel 8.2: Encountering a 404 Error on Route Access
When I run my Laravel project locally, I do not get any 404 errors, but when I transfer it to the server, I get 404 errors on some pages. There is no problem on the listing pages, but I cannot access the form pages.
web.php
Route::get('/kategori/ekle', [CategoryController::class, 'create'])->name('categories.create');

The store function with the same url route is defined, but when I make it different, the urls do not work again.
Controller
public function create()
{
    return view('categories.create');
}

I cleared the caches and checked the list.

Check the file names of your controllers. While locally casing does not matter, on a server it does. Check the storage/logs folder for the log files. Most of the time you will find more info there. Another possibility is that the routes are cached, and you added the route. run php artisan route:clear to clear the route cache

I checked the names of the controllers and there are no errors. Also, since I could not find a terminal in cpanel, I deleted the route caches as a different alternative Route::get('/clear-route-cache', function() {     Artisan::call('route:clear');     return 'Route cache cleared'; }); as follows. In addition, I checked the c panel error logs and storage / logs. No error is returned from there

Case Sensitivity on the Server: Servers, especially those running on Linux, are case-sensitive with file paths and URLs, unlike Windows, which is case-insensitive. Double-check that your controller and view filenames match the case exactly as referenced in your code.
For example:
If your view file is named create.blade.php, ensure it’s not accidentally named Create.blade.php.
Double-check that the correct controller is imported in your web.php routes file. If you are using namespaces or have multiple controllers with similar names, ensure the right one is being used.
